# Detect XAML FlipView swipe states

Tags: c#, xaml

```
<FlipView x:Name="CameraFilpView" 
          ManipulationMode="All" 
          ManipulationStarted="CameraFilpView_ManipulationStarted" 
          ManipulationDelta="CameraFilpView_ManipulationDelta" 
          ManipulationCompleted="CameraFilpView_ManipulationCompleted">
</FlipView>
```

I'm trying to detect the swipe gesture state of the FlipView component but none of my events are used. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using ScrollViewer and HorizontalSnapPoints instead of FlipView.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to use manipulation events?
Manipulation events are generally used when the control is to be dragged.

If you only need to know that flipview swiped than you can use SelectionChanged event of FlipView.

Comment: I need to know how the swiping state is because I want to slide in/slide out a bottom bar on different flipview items. SelectionChanged is too late in my case.